# C# алгоритм для вычисления МДНФ по картам Карно

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Подскажите алгоритм вычисления МДНФ(минимизированная дизъюнктивная нормальная форма) из таблицы в программе,чтобы программа по таблице находила МДНФ.Как его реализовать по ячейкам или каким-то другим примером.Видел в нете массу примеров и ни одного с ячейками.Если додумаюсь сам-поделюсь с вами.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вроде же карты Карно и диаграммы Вейче нельзя запрограммировать?

Comment: Можно,когдато даже дипломные работы писались(тогда это было актуально).
Есть даже готовый калькулятор http://tablica-istinnosti.ru/ru/ (вкладка "Вектор значений")
Погуляйте гуглом и вы увидите множество алгоритмов.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй почитать здесь http://alnam.ru/book_spre.php?id=14 , может чем-то поможет. Можете попытаться реализовать как написано в книге, с полным перебором тупиковых форм, обычно оно работает достаточно быстро.